# Как быстро достать из строки несколько чисел на С++?

Tags: c++, c

Имеется вот такая строка: `v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000`

На обычном Си делаю так `sscanf(line, "%s %lf %lf %lf", str, &x, &y, &z);`

Есть ли какой-то аналог этого на плюсах? И чтобы не потерялась скорость при доставании чисел.

Так же есть другая строка: `f 1/2/3 2/3/4 3/6 4/6`

Из неё нужно вытащить 4 числа (самое первое перед слешем). Причем, может быть нужно будет достать больше чем 4, например, 1/2 2/3 4/5 6/7 8/9, тут надо достать 5 (1, 2, 4, 6, 8). На обычном Си сделал это через strtok и sscanf (разделаю по пробелам и sscanf'ом он автоматически вычленяет первое число до слеша).

Таких строк может быть несколько десятков тысяч.
Как такое провернуть на плюсах без потери производительности?

Comment: Вообще-то у вас или одна `s` лишняя, или аргумента не хватает, и лишний пробел после `%`... `cin >> str >> x >> y >> z;` устраивает? О производительности - вы уже точно знаете, что именно здесь затык по скорости в вашей программе? Профилировали?

Comment: Забыл дописать "line". У меня есть строка line (как char* line). И из неё нужно вытащить в переменные 3 числа.

Comment: *"И чтобы не потерялась скорость"* - ¿А она была? А еще до погони за скоростью стоит озаботиться корректностью преобразований. Не забывайте, что `if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined`. `sscanf` годится разве что для учебных целей

Comment: Ну тогда вместо `cout` воспользуйтесь `istringstream`, на `line` построенном.

Comment: @user7860670, `sscanf` отлично подходит для решения задачи. Почему только "учебные цели"?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я же вроде расписал почему - UB если строка не может быть корректно распарсена и сомнительная скорость работы.

Comment: @user7860670, `sscanf` может быть сконфигурирован так что UB будет невозможно. Работает он быстрее любых других средств форматного ввода. Нормальная штука для прикладного программиста. Пользоваться трудно - это да.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy *"sscanf может быть сконфигурирован так что UB будет невозможно"* не может, в этом и проблема. Обращаю внимание, что речь не шла про ситуации, когда паттерн не совпадает с аргументом или что-то подобное, UB возможно когда все корректно вызывается. *"Работает он быстрее любых других средств форматного ввода."* - то-то люди изо всех сил пилят собственные парсеры. https://lemire.me/blog/2020/03/10/fast-float-parsing-in-practice/

Comment: @user7860670, парсеры пилят быстрые за счёт точности - известная проблема: если вводить вещественные числа с минимальной потерей точности, это накладно. Про UB: приведите пример. Я уверен что `sscanf` к UB не приводит, возвращает ошибку или число считанных полей и всё.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Парсеры не только быстрые, но и корректные. Что касается UB, то я уже привел цитату из стандарта. Вот пример: `int i{}; ::std::sscanf("12345678901234567890", "%i", i);`

Comment: @user7860670, вы правы по обоим пунктам. Признаю себя ослом.

Comment: regexp вам нужен. На Питоне, например, такое в пару строк можно написать. На Си(++) в принципе тоже с применением соответствующей бтблиотеки.